# why webpack output is always main.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-cli

I have project with this structure:

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ dist/   
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.css
│  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ index.html
├─ package.json
├─ webpack.config.js
```

My webpack.js is:

```
const { Module } = require("webpack");
Module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
    }
}
```

When I run the command `npx webpack` or `npm run build`, the output file is always saved as `dist/main.js` instead of `dist/bundle.js`

Any ideas of what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a same question like your. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539943/webpack-output-filename-config-not-working , try to restart your IDE, resave your webpack.config.js

Comment: I don't think there is a named export `Module` exported in webpack. it's suppose to be `module.exports`.

Comment: Upload a minimal sample to github to look and try it

Answer (score 1):

The [docs (for webpack 5)](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) give several options for setting the `entry` property. You are using the "Single Entry" way. Here is what the docs say about it:

> **Single Entry (Shorthand) Syntax**
>
> ````
> module.exports = {```
>     entry: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',```
> };
> ````
>
> [this] single entry syntax for the entry property is a shorthand for:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>     entry: {
>         main: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
>     },
> };
> ```

So just to reiterate, by doing

```
entry: './src/index.js',
```

in your config file, you are unknowingly using shorthand and setting the name of the bundled file to `main.js`.

If you look at the doc page linked above, you'll see that there could be several ways to fix this, but one way would be to replace your current `entry` property with:

```
entry: {
     'bundle': './src/index.js'
},
```